# Delete Array Element From Multidimensional Infinity Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

There is a specific element I want to delete.
For example, I want to delete the element with `id = 76` in the array below. Also, the array can go together indefinitely.

The problem here is that I cannot refresh the page because I do instant action with Vue.js.
If I can do this, my next question is probably how can I add an element where I want it now :)

```
[
    {
        "id": 6,
        "place": 100,
        "header_tr": "KURUMSAL",
        "header_en": "CORPORATE",
        "content_tr": "kurumsal",
        "content_en": "corporate",
        "visible_main_status": "Aktif",
        "created_at": "2020-05-24 01:02:36",
        "updated_at": "2020-05-24 01:02:36",
        "deleted_at": null,
        "navigation_sub_categories": [
            {
                "id": 10,
                "navigation_main_category_id": 6,
                "navigation_sub_category_id": null,
                "place": 100,
                "header_tr": "Vizyonumuz ve Misyonumuz",
                "header_en": "Vizyonumuz ve Misyonumuz",
                "content_tr": "vizyonumuz-ve-misyonumuz",
                "content_en": "vizyonumuz-ve-misyonumuz",
                "href_tr": "vizyonumuz-ve-misyonumuz",
                "href_en": "vizyonumuz-ve-misyonumuz",
                "constant_status": "İç Link",
                "visible_main_status": "Aktif",
                "created_at": "2020-05-24 01:08:59",
                "updated_at": "2020-05-24 01:08:59",
                "deleted_at": null,
                "navigation_sub_categories": [],
                "dynamic_fixed_pages": []
            },
            {
                "id": 11,
                "navigation_main_category_id": 6,
                "navigation_sub_category_id": null,
                "place": 99,
                "header_tr": "Temel Değerlerimiz ve Yönetim Politikamız",
                "header_en": "Temel Değerlerimiz ve Yönetim Politikamız",
                "content_tr": "Temel Değerlerimiz ve Yönetim Politikamız",
                "content_en": "Temel Değerlerimiz ve Yönetim Politikamız",
                "href_tr": "Temel Değerlerimiz ve Yönetim Politikamız",
                "href_en": "Temel Değerlerimiz ve Yönetim Politikamız",
                "constant_status": "İç Link",
                "visible_main_status": "Aktif",
                "created_at": "2020-05-24 01:09:26",
                "updated_at": "2020-05-24 01:09:26",
                "deleted_at": null,
                "navigation_sub_categories": [],
                "dynamic_fixed_pages": []
            },
            {
                "id": 12,
                "navigation_main_category_id": 6,
                "navigation_sub_category_id": null,
                "place": 98,
                "header_tr": "Organizasyon Yapısı",
                "header_en": "Organizasyon Yapısı",
                "content_tr": "Organizasyon Yapısı",
                "content_en": "Organizasyon Yapısı",
                "href_tr": "Organizasyon Yapısı",
                "href_en": "Organizasyon Yapısı",
                "constant_status": "İç Link",
                "visible_main_status": "Aktif",
                "created_at": "2020-05-24 01:10:33",
                "updated_at": "2020-05-24 01:10:33",
                "deleted_at": null,
                "navigation_sub_categories": [
                    {
                        "id": 19,
                        "navigation_main_category_id": 6,
                        "navigation_sub_category_id": 12,
                        "place": 100,
                        "header_tr": "Yönetim Kurulu",
                        "header_en": "Yönetim Kurulu",
                        "content_tr": "/tr/kurumsal/organizasyon-yapilari/yonetim-kurulu",
                        "content_en": "/en/kurumsal/organizasyon-yapilari/yonetim-kurulu",
                        "href_tr": "Yönetim Kurulu",
                        "href_en": "Yönetim Kurulu",
                        "constant_status": "İç Link",
                        "visible_main_status": "Aktif",
                        "created_at": "2020-05-24 01:13:27",
                        "updated_at": "2020-05-26 08:58:49",
                        "deleted_at": null,
                        "navigation_sub_categories": [],
                        "dynamic_fixed_pages": []
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 20,
                        "navigation_main_category_id": 6,
                        "navigation_sub_category_id": 12,
                        "place": 99,
                        "header_tr": "Meclis",
                        "header_en": "Meclis",
                        "content_tr": "Meclis",
                        "content_en": "Meclis",
                        "href_tr": "Meclis",
                        "href_en": "Meclis",
                        "constant_status": "İç Link",
                        "visible_main_status": "Aktif",
                        "created_at": "2020-05-24 01:13:46",
                        "updated_at": "2020-05-24 01:13:46",
                        "deleted_at": null,
                        "navigation_sub_categories": [],
                        "dynamic_fixed_pages": []
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 21,
                        "navigation_main_category_id": 6,
                        "navigation_sub_category_id": 12,
                        "place": 98,
                        "header_tr": "Disiplin Kurulu",
                        "header_en": "Disiplin Kurulu",
                        "content_tr": "Disiplin Kurulu",
                        "content_en": "Disiplin Kurulu",
                        "href_tr": "Disiplin Kurulu",
                        "href_en": "Disiplin Kurulu",
                        "constant_status": "İç Link",
                        "visible_main_status": "Aktif",
                        "created_at": "2020-05-24 01:14:06",
                        "updated_at": "2020-05-24 01:14:06",
                        "deleted_at": null,
                        "navigation_sub_categories": [],
                        "dynamic_fixed_pages": []
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 22,
                        "navigation_main_category_id": 6,
                        "navigation_sub_category_id": 12,
                        "place": 97,
                        "header_tr": "Meslek Komiteleri Üyeleri",
                        "header_en": "Meslek Komiteleri Üyeleri",
                        "content_tr": "Meslek Komiteleri Üyeleri",
                        "content_en": "Meslek Komiteleri Üyeleri",
                        "href_tr": "Meslek Komiteleri Üyeleri",
                        "href_en": "Meslek Komiteleri Üyeleri",
                        "constant_status": "İç Link",
                        "visible_main_status": "Aktif",
                        "created_at": "2020-05-24 01:14:32",
                        "updated_at": "2020-05-24 01:14:32",
                        "deleted_at": null,
                        "navigation_sub_categories": [
                            {
                                "id": 23,
                                "navigation_main_category_id": 6,
                                "navigation_sub_category_id": 22,
                                "place": 100,
                                "header_tr": "Meslek Altı",
                                "header_en": "Meslek Altı",
                                "content_tr": "Meslek Altı",
                                "content_en": "Meslek Altı",
                                "href_tr": "Meslek Altı",
                                "href_en": "Meslek Altı",
                                "constant_status": "İç Link",
                                "visible_main_status": "Pasif",
                                "created_at": "2020-05-24 11:32:00",
                                "updated_at": "2020-05-24 11:32:00",
                                "deleted_at": null,
                                "navigation_sub_categories": [
                                    {
                                        "id": 24,
                                        "navigation_main_category_id": 6,
                                        "navigation_sub_category_id": 23,
                                        "place": 100,
                                        "header_tr": "Meslek Alt Alt",
                                        "header_en": "Meslek Alt Alt",
                                        "content_tr": "Meslek Alt Alt",
                                        "content_en": "Meslek Alt Alt",
                                        "href_tr": "Meslek Alt Alt",
                                        "href_en": "Meslek Alt Alt",
                                        "constant_status": "İç Link",
                                        "visible_main_status": "Pasif",
                                        "created_at": "2020-05-24 11:33:20",
                                        "updated_at": "2020-05-24 11:33:20",
                                        "deleted_at": null,
                                        "navigation_sub_categories": [],
                                        "dynamic_fixed_pages": []
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "id": 76,
                                        "navigation_main_category_id": 6,
                                        "navigation_sub_category_id": 23,
                                        "place": 44,
                                        "header_tr": "44",
                                        "header_en": "44",
                                        "content_tr": null,
                                        "content_en": null,
                                        "href_tr": null,
                                        "href_en": null,
                                        "constant_status": "İç Link",
                                        "visible_main_status": "Aktif",
                                        "created_at": "2020-09-24 12:51:25",
                                        "updated_at": "2020-09-24 12:51:25",
                                        "deleted_at": null,
                                        "navigation_sub_categories": [],
                                        "dynamic_fixed_pages": []
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "id": 79,
                                        "navigation_main_category_id": 6,
                                        "navigation_sub_category_id": 23,
                                        "place": 77,
                                        "header_tr": "77",
                                        "header_en": "77",
                                        "content_tr": null,
                                        "content_en": null,
                                        "href_tr": null,
                                        "href_en": null,
                                        "constant_status": "İç Link",
                                        "visible_main_status": "Aktif",
                                        "created_at": "2020-09-24 12:51:43",
                                        "updated_at": "2020-09-24 12:51:43",
                                        "deleted_at": null,
                                        "navigation_sub_categories": [],
                                        "dynamic_fixed_pages": []
                                    }
                                ],
                                "dynamic_fixed_pages": []
                            }
                        ],
                        "dynamic_fixed_pages": []
                    }
                ],
                "dynamic_fixed_pages": []
            },
            {
                "id": 13,
                "navigation_main_category_id": 6,
                "navigation_sub_category_id": null,
                "place": 97,
                "header_tr": "Meclis Konuşmaları",
                "header_en": "Meclis Konuşmaları",
                "content_tr": "Meclis Konuşmaları",
                "content_en": "Meclis Konuşmaları",
                "href_tr": "Meclis Konuşmaları",
                "href_en": "Meclis Konuşmaları",
                "constant_status": "İç Link",
                "visible_main_status": "Aktif",
                "created_at": "2020-05-24 01:11:21",
                "updated_at": "2020-05-24 01:11:21",
                "deleted_at": null,
                "navigation_sub_categories": [],
                "dynamic_fixed_pages": []
            },
            {
                "id": 14,
                "navigation_main_category_id": 6,
                "navigation_sub_category_id": null,
                "place": 96,
                "header_tr": "Logo",
                "header_en": "Logo",
                "content_tr": "Logo",
                "content_en": "Logo",
                "href_tr": "Logo",
                "href_en": "Logo",
                "constant_status": "İç Link",
                "visible_main_status": "Aktif",
                "created_at": "2020-05-24 01:11:39",
                "updated_at": "2020-05-24 01:11:39",
                "deleted_at": null,
                "navigation_sub_categories": [],
                "dynamic_fixed_pages": []
            },
            {
                "id": 15,
                "navigation_main_category_id": 6,
                "navigation_sub_category_id": null,
                "place": 96,
                "header_tr": "Oda Hesapları",
                "header_en": "Oda Hesapları",
                "content_tr": "Oda Hesapları",
                "content_en": "Oda Hesapları",
                "href_tr": "Oda Hesapları",
                "href_en": "Oda Hesapları",
                "constant_status": "İç Link",
                "visible_main_status": "Aktif",
                "created_at": "2020-05-24 01:11:58",
                "updated_at": "2020-05-24 01:11:58",
                "deleted_at": null,
                "navigation_sub_categories": [],
                "dynamic_fixed_pages": []
            },
            {
                "id": 16,
                "navigation_main_category_id": 6,
                "navigation_sub_category_id": null,
                "place": 95,
                "header_tr": "Stratejik Planlar ve Çalışma Programları",
                "header_en": "Stratejik Planlar ve Çalışma Programları",
                "content_tr": "Stratejik Planlar ve Çalışma Programları",
                "content_en": "Stratejik Planlar ve Çalışma Programları",
                "href_tr": "Stratejik Planlar ve Çalışma Programları",
                "href_en": "Stratejik Planlar ve Çalışma Programları",
                "constant_status": "İç Link",
                "visible_main_status": "Aktif",
                "created_at": "2020-05-24 01:12:17",
                "updated_at": "2020-05-24 01:12:17",
                "deleted_at": null,
                "navigation_sub_categories": [],
                "dynamic_fixed_pages": []
            },
            {
                "id": 17,
                "navigation_main_category_id": 6,
                "navigation_sub_category_id": null,
                "place": 94,
                "header_tr": "Kardeş Odalar",
                "header_en": "Kardeş Odalar",
                "content_tr": "Kardeş Odalar",
                "content_en": "Kardeş Odalar",
                "href_tr": "Kardeş Odalar",
                "href_en": "Kardeş Odalar",
                "constant_status": "İç Link",
                "visible_main_status": "Aktif",
                "created_at": "2020-05-24 01:12:36",
                "updated_at": "2020-05-24 01:12:36",
                "deleted_at": null,
                "navigation_sub_categories": [],
                "dynamic_fixed_pages": []
            },
            {
                "id": 18,
                "navigation_main_category_id": 6,
                "navigation_sub_category_id": null,
                "place": 94,
                "header_tr": "KVKK",
                "header_en": "KVKK",
                "content_tr": "KVKK",
                "content_en": "KVKK",
                "href_tr": "KVKK",
                "href_en": "KVKK",
                "constant_status": "İç Link",
                "visible_main_status": "Aktif",
                "created_at": "2020-05-24 01:12:55",
                "updated_at": "2020-05-24 01:12:55",
                "deleted_at": null,
                "navigation_sub_categories": [
                    {
                        "id": 27,
                        "navigation_main_category_id": 6,
                        "navigation_sub_category_id": 18,
                        "place": 10,
                        "header_tr": "Test Kvkk Alt",
                        "header_en": "Test Kvkk Alt EN",
                        "content_tr": "Test Kvkk Alt",
                        "content_en": "Test Kvkk Alt EN",
                        "href_tr": "test-kvkk-alt-tr",
                        "href_en": "test-kvkk-alt-en",
                        "constant_status": "İç Link",
                        "visible_main_status": "Aktif",
                        "created_at": "2020-09-21 13:10:38",
                        "updated_at": "2020-09-21 13:10:38",
                        "deleted_at": null,
                        "navigation_sub_categories": [],
                        "dynamic_fixed_pages": []
                    }
                ],
                "dynamic_fixed_pages": []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 12,
        "navigation_main_category_id": 6,
        "navigation_sub_category_id": null,
        "place": 98,
        "header_tr": "Organizasyon Yapısı",
        "header_en": "Organizasyon Yapısı",
        "content_tr": "Organizasyon Yapısı",
        "content_en": "Organizasyon Yapısı",
        "href_tr": "Organizasyon Yapısı",
        "href_en": "Organizasyon Yapısı",
        "constant_status": "İç Link",
        "visible_main_status": "Aktif",
        "created_at": "2020-05-24 01:10:33",
        "updated_at": "2020-05-24 01:10:33",
        "deleted_at": null,
        "navigation_sub_categories": [
            {
                "id": 19,
                "navigation_main_category_id": 6,
                "navigation_sub_category_id": 12,
                "place": 100,
                "header_tr": "Yönetim Kurulu",
                "header_en": "Yönetim Kurulu",
                "content_tr": "/tr/kurumsal/organizasyon-yapilari/yonetim-kurulu",
                "content_en": "/en/kurumsal/organizasyon-yapilari/yonetim-kurulu",
                "href_tr": "Yönetim Kurulu",
                "href_en": "Yönetim Kurulu",
                "constant_status": "İç Link",
                "visible_main_status": "Aktif",
                "created_at": "2020-05-24 01:13:27",
                "updated_at": "2020-05-26 08:58:49",
                "deleted_at": null,
                "navigation_sub_categories": [],
                "dynamic_fixed_pages": []
            },
            {
                "id": 20,
                "navigation_main_category_id": 6,
                "navigation_sub_category_id": 12,
                "place": 99,
                "header_tr": "Meclis",
                "header_en": "Meclis",
                "content_tr": "Meclis",
                "content_en": "Meclis",
                "href_tr": "Meclis",
                "href_en": "Meclis",
                "constant_status": "İç Link",
                "visible_main_status": "Aktif",
                "created_at": "2020-05-24 01:13:46",
                "updated_at": "2020-05-24 01:13:46",
                "deleted_at": null,
                "navigation_sub_categories": [],
                "dynamic_fixed_pages": []
            },
            {
                "id": 21,
                "navigation_main_category_id": 6,
                "navigation_sub_category_id": 12,
                "place": 98,
                "header_tr": "Disiplin Kurulu",
                "header_en": "Disiplin Kurulu",
                "content_tr": "Disiplin Kurulu",
                "content_en": "Disiplin Kurulu",
                "href_tr": "Disiplin Kurulu",
                "href_en": "Disiplin Kurulu",
                "constant_status": "İç Link",
                "visible_main_status": "Aktif",
                "created_at": "2020-05-24 01:14:06",
                "updated_at": "2020-05-24 01:14:06",
                "deleted_at": null,
                "navigation_sub_categories": [],
                "dynamic_fixed_pages": []
            },
            {
                "id": 22,
                "navigation_main_category_id": 6,
                "navigation_sub_category_id": 12,
                "place": 97,
                "header_tr": "Meslek Komiteleri Üyeleri",
                "header_en": "Meslek Komiteleri Üyeleri",
                "content_tr": "Meslek Komiteleri Üyeleri",
                "content_en": "Meslek Komiteleri Üyeleri",
                "href_tr": "Meslek Komiteleri Üyeleri",
                "href_en": "Meslek Komiteleri Üyeleri",
                "constant_status": "İç Link",
                "visible_main_status": "Aktif",
                "created_at": "2020-05-24 01:14:32",
                "updated_at": "2020-05-24 01:14:32",
                "deleted_at": null,
                "navigation_sub_categories": [
                    {
                        "id": 23,
                        "navigation_main_category_id": 6,
                        "navigation_sub_category_id": 22,
                        "place": 100,
                        "header_tr": "Meslek Altı",
                        "header_en": "Meslek Altı",
                        "content_tr": "Meslek Altı",
                        "content_en": "Meslek Altı",
                        "href_tr": "Meslek Altı",
                        "href_en": "Meslek Altı",
                        "constant_status": "İç Link",
                        "visible_main_status": "Pasif",
                        "created_at": "2020-05-24 11:32:00",
                        "updated_at": "2020-05-24 11:32:00",
                        "deleted_at": null,
                        "navigation_sub_categories": [
                            {
                                "id": 24,
                                "navigation_main_category_id": 6,
                                "navigation_sub_category_id": 23,
                                "place": 100,
                                "header_tr": "Meslek Alt Alt",
                                "header_en": "Meslek Alt Alt",
                                "content_tr": "Meslek Alt Alt",
                                "content_en": "Meslek Alt Alt",
                                "href_tr": "Meslek Alt Alt",
                                "href_en": "Meslek Alt Alt",
                                "constant_status": "İç Link",
                                "visible_main_status": "Pasif",
                                "created_at": "2020-05-24 11:33:20",
                                "updated_at": "2020-05-24 11:33:20",
                                "deleted_at": null,
                                "navigation_sub_categories": [],
                                "dynamic_fixed_pages": []
                            },
                            **{
                                "id": 76,
                                "navigation_main_category_id": 6,
                                "navigation_sub_category_id": 23,
                                "place": 44,
                                "header_tr": "44",
                                "header_en": "44",
                                "content_tr": null,
                                "content_en": null,
                                "href_tr": null,
                                "href_en": null,
                                "constant_status": "İç Link",
                                "visible_main_status": "Aktif",
                                "created_at": "2020-09-24 12:51:25",
                                "updated_at": "2020-09-24 12:51:25",
                                "deleted_at": null,
                                "navigation_sub_categories": [],
                                "dynamic_fixed_pages": []
                            },**
                            {
                                "id": 79,
                                "navigation_main_category_id": 6,
                                "navigation_sub_category_id": 23,
                                "place": 77,
                                "header_tr": "77",
                                "header_en": "77",
                                "content_tr": null,
                                "content_en": null,
                                "href_tr": null,
                                "href_en": null,
                                "constant_status": "İç Link",
                                "visible_main_status": "Aktif",
                                "created_at": "2020-09-24 12:51:43",
                                "updated_at": "2020-09-24 12:51:43",
                                "deleted_at": null,
                                "navigation_sub_categories": [],
                                "dynamic_fixed_pages": []
                            }
                        ],
                        "dynamic_fixed_pages": []
                    }
                ],
                "dynamic_fixed_pages": []
            }
        ],
        "dynamic_fixed_pages": []
    }
]
```

Comment: Arrays cannot be infinite in JavaScript. Also, are all those properties in your data relevant to the question? Can you simplify the data to the bare minimum? What went wrong when you tried to delete an element?

Comment: you are not clear what u want... minimize your question and example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Salamu Aleykum.
Try:

```
const filterObject = (object, id) => {
    const newObj = [];
    object.map((element) => {
        if (parseInt(element.id) === parseInt(id)) return;

        if (element.navigation_sub_categories)
            element.navigation_sub_categories = filterObject(element.navigation_sub_categories, id);
        /* Eger `navigation_sub_categories`-den basqa keyde varsa array tipli asagidakini test ede bilersen */
        // Object.entries(element).map(
        //  ([k, v]) => typeof v === "object" && Array.isArray(v) && (element[k] = filterObject(v, id)),
        // );

        newObj.push(element);
    });
    return newObj;
};

filterObject(/* object */, idWhicYouNeedDelete)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!
So how do I add items to the array?

Comment: Yes. But it's few hard than get. If you want create question and i submit there too.

Comment: I tried it myself but I was not successful. Can you help me with the link here?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64052339/adding-elements-to-the-multidimensional-array

@MDReal